# 2 exact same iOS app exept that the database is different

Tags: ios, xcode

I actually have one app running with on database and I want to make a second app like the first one exept that the database will be different. What is the best thing to do? Is duplicate xCode Project the best solution?

Thanks everyone,

Ben

Comment: I'd say it depends on the usage of the app(s) ? App Store ? You ? Specific client ?

Comment: Hi, it is for the App Store !

Comment: What's the difference between the databases ? Can the user use either one ?

Comment: The difference is the data and one database for one app. I have to have 2 apps at the end, but duplicate the project is you think, the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app will be exactly the same but the data in the database is gonna be different, then you should just use the same code base but with a different bundle identifier. To do that you could duplicate the Xcode project, or to make things simpler, you could use one project but change the bundle identifier only before building for the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Init a git repository and make a different branch, then if you have modifications in your master repository you don't have to change two different projects.

Answer (score 1):

Just have two targets, and check the bundle identifier at runtime to switch data(base).